# How do I round a number down to the closest 10000 in Flutter?

Tags: math, flutter, dart, rounding

How do I round down number `10999` to `10000`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following code:

```
int x = 10999;
int divisor = 10000; 
int result = (x / divisor).floor() * divisor;
```

Or using integer divisoin:

```
int x = 10999;
int divisor = 10000; 
int result = (x ~/ divisor) * divisor;
```

Comment: Note that the `floor()` approach will round toward negative infinity and the integer division approach will round toward zero.  That won't matter for 10999, but it would matter if rounding negative numbers.